# CommandError: No installed app with label 'inheritance', Are you sure your INSTALLED_APPS setting is correct?

Tags: django

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'inheritance',
)
```

This is way I have mentioned the app 'inheritance' in  the setting file of  Django Project . Is there anything that I have to followed in order get rid of the error

I am getting this error when I am running the command

```
python manage.py sqlall inheritance/
```

This is my directory Structure

```
Documentation/
   ├── Abstract/
   ├── db.sqlite3
   ├── Documentation/
   |── inheritance/
   └── manage.py
```

Comment: Try this: `$ python manage.py shell` and then `> import inheritance`. Do you have an app witgh module name "inheritance" in django's python path?

Comment: @FreekWiekmeijer , pythonpath means where the manage.py exist ? right . I have followed what you just told me , but same problem persists.

Comment: Pythonpath is where python's `import` statement looks for packages and modules. You can print the pythonpath using `import sys; print sys.path`. Did the `import inheritance` succeed of did it give an ImportError?

Comment: /home/sagar/myenv/Documentation'  It is giving the long list but related one for question is this . Documentation is Project , inside this there is app inheritance

Comment: The only relevant part of the pythonpath is whether it contains `inheritance`. If you open the django shell (`python manage.py shell`), you should be able to import each app from the `INSTALLED_APPS` list. i.e. `import django.contrib.messages` or `import inheritance`.

Comment: I just created another app Abstract , even that is not there in list

Comment: Maybe post your directory structure?

Comment: Do you have an `__init__.py` in your inheritance directory ?

Comment: yup it is there in inheritance